# Message/logging from Thin

Tags: ruby, logging, rack, thin

How can I stop <strike>Rack</strike> Thin from returning initial messages of the following type?

> >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>   >> Maximum connections set to 1024
>   >> istening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop

I am using it like this:

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new do
    map("/resource/"){run(Rack::File.new("/"))}
    map("/") do
        run(->env{
            h = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env["QUERY_STRING"])
            [200, {},[routine_to_generate_dynamic_content(h)]]
        })
    end
end, Port: 3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages does not come from rack, they come from thin: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/server.rb#L150 You can set the logging preferences according to this: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/logging.rb Thin::Logging.silent = true, but do you really want to silence all? Maybe direct it to a log file instead of stdout?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the initial messages are coming from [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin). As per their Github Issue #31, [Disabling all logging](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/31), you can add `Thin::Logging.silent = true` before the rest of the code to silence the initial messages.

However, this will also silence all other messages from the Thin adapter. A glance at [the source](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/server.rb) says these other messages will also be silenced:

- `Waiting for n connection(s) to finish, can take up to n sec, CTRL+C to stop now`
- `Stopping ...`
- `!! Ruby 1.8.5 is not secure please install cgi_multipart_eof_fix:` 
      `gem install cgi_multipart_eof_fix`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful!